# Ullrich's complex analysis 1.2: Why it would not be corret to write the derivative of analytic function in this form?

Tags: complex-analysis

This comes from Ullrich. D's complex made simple, exercise 1.2.

Suppose the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$ has radius of convergence $R>0$, and define $f : D(0, R) \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$$

We know that
$$f'(z) = \sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^{\infty} n c_n z^{n-1} \quad (z \in D(0,R))$$

But the author says that it would not be quite correct to write
$$f'(z) = \sum_{n=\color{red}{0}}^{\infty} n c_n z^{n-1} \quad (z \in D(0,R))$$

although it is correct to say $f' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n'$, where $f_n(z)=c_n z^n$.

I don't see what is different, only thing that I can tell is that just the first term of the first series is just $c_1$, but the second series starts with $0 \frac{1}{z}=0$ and the second term is $c_1$.

But this difference makes no real difference, doesn't it?

Could you explain what is different?

Comment: $f_0(z)=c_0$ and $f'_0(z)=0$. It would be between strange and wrong to write it as $f'_0(z) = 0 \cdot \frac{1}{z}$ because that looks too much like the product of two functions, one of which is undefined at $0$.

Comment: It's semantics mostly. As you note, the first term is $0$, however in the form it is written in, it is not strictly a power series. It's a Laurent series.

Comment: Mostly, but not entirely. The domain now excludes $z=0$, which of course we do not intend.

Comment: True true, though it's a removable discontinuity and can be filled with the Riemann removable singularity theorem, so no real harm done either way.